# Gravity's Rainbow: An accidental nominal similarity in science and literature?

Tags: physics, theoretical-physics, relativity-theory, gravity, physics-social-history

There is an interesting extension of Einstein's Special Relativity, known as [Doubly Special Relativity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubly_special_relativity) (presented after 2002) in which there is not only an observer-independent maximum velocity (i.e., the speed of light), but also, an observer-independent maximum energy scale (i.e., the Planck energy). Generalizing this idea in the presence of gravity led to the [Doubly General Relativity](https://arxiv.org/abs/1206.4823) (introduced 2004) which is generally referred to as [Gravity's Rainbow](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0264-9381/21/7/001/meta) (in addition, there is [another paper in 1995](http://Gravity%E2%80%99s%20rainbow:%20Limits%20for%20the%20applicability%20of%20the%20equivalence%20principle), before the discovery of Doubly Special Relativity!, in which the authors have been used the term "Gravity’s rainbow"). Interestingly, the novelist [Thomas Pynchon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomas_Pynchon) had already written a dense, complex and fictional novel entitled "[Gravity's Rainbow in 1973](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravity%27s_Rainbow)".

I strongly feel there is a connection between these nominal similarities in science (physics) and literature. **Does anyone know anything about this?** Please inform me if you know anything.

*Thank you very much in advance ...*

Comment: Smolin writes in Trouble with Physics:"*In our version, photons that have more energy travel faster... It took somewhat longer to show that this led to a version of a variable-speed-of-light theory that was also consistent with the principles of general relativity, but we eventually got there, too. We call this theory 'Gravity's Rainbow after Thomas Pynchon's novel. 'Doubly special relativity' is a stupid name, but it has stuck.*" Light splitting by gravity is not what 'rainbow' alludes to in Pynchon's title, so apparently it was appropriated just for the pop-culture value.

Comment: @Conifold- Hi, thanks for your great information. I didn't know that. I should read Smolin's book (I heard a lot about it). Now, thanks to you, I have a reason for this nominal similarity.